# How can I deal with "Eigennamen" when they conflict with the grammar of the sentence?

Tags: proper-noun

Imagine a street being named "Alte Straße". Which of the following sentences is correct?

> "Ein Haus in der Alten Straße"

> "Ein Haus in der Alte Straße"

The first one seems more intuitive, as it is grammatically consistent, but it changes the "Eigenname" of the street. It also risks people not recognizing that this is the name of the street, and instead thinking I am referring to some old street.

The second one seems odd. It would cause me to stop, do a double take, and then ponder if the author made a mistake or not. But it has the upside of using the correct name of the street.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Eigennamen get inflected as well (see [Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Die-Deklination-von-Firmennamen), [GfdS](https://gfds.de/firmennamen-beugung-von/)), which means

> Ein Haus in der Alten Straße

is correct.

In written language, people should understand you're referring to the street name "Alte Straße" and not to an old street, as the first letter of the street is always written as a capital letter (see [Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/strassennamen)) and the actual name of the street, not a description of it.

If you're really eager to emphasize that it's a street name, you could rephrase it to "Ein Haus in der Straße mit dem Namen 'Alte Straße'". However, this would sound pretty stilted and there's probably no need for it.

Comment: There are some exceptions to the standard rule, e.g., ["Alter Markt" and "Hohe Straße"](https://www.korrekturen.de/forum.pl/md/read/id/8222/sbj/der-alter-markt-alte-markt/) in Cologne, where the official spelling uses two words, even though they are inflected as if they were single words ("Altermarkt", "Hohestraße").

Comment: The stilted long way of saying things was a long-running theme in the satirical party "Die Partei": "Die Anhänger der Partei Die Partei haben sich das alte DDR-Lied 'Die Partei Die Partei, die hat immer recht' zur Hymne gewählt."

Comment: If an element of a proper name is inflected depends also on the fact which part of the name it belongs to. E.g.: the RAF is called *die Rote Armee Fraktion*, but *Rote* refers to *Armee*, not *Fraktion*. Thus, the name could be correctly inclined to *(in) der Rote Armee Fraktion* (dative). However, *in der Rote**n** Armee Fraktion* is also heard sometimes, be it only out of habit.

Comment: @Uwe I thought it was _Huhstrooß_ auf Kölsch. That's what BAP taught me.

Comment: @SQB In Kölsch. yes. But I was talking about standard German.

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to add something to the other answer, since there's more semantic distinctions to it.  Proper nouns enjoy a spectrum here, ranging from the same inflective behaviour as common nouns have to becoming essentially uninflectable quotations used as noun phrases.

The criterion is an interaction of whether the noun phrase is grammatically transparent with the null-article and inflection rules for proper nouns.  This depends on semantics (asterisks marking [ungrammatical examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk#Ungrammaticality)):

- Phrase is transparent, and needs an article (because is an *Ortsname*):

  > *Der Anfang der "Alte Straße"
  >
  > Der Anfang der Alten Straße
- Phrase is transparent, but can be used with *Nullartikel* (since it is a kind of *Produktname*):

  > Der Bassist von "Würzige Melonen"
  >
  > Der Bassist der Würzigen Melonen
- Phrase is not transparent (*ohne* alone cannot be inflected as a noun), cannot be used with article (*Produktname* again):

  > Der Regisseur von "[Oben](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oben)"
  >
  > *Der Regisseur des Obens
- Phrase is not transparent, and must be used with article (*Bergname*):

  > Der Gipfel des K2(s?)
  >
  > *Der Gipfel von K2

Note that if the band's name were *Alte Straße*, you would say *der Bassist von "Alte Straße"* as well!

Obviously, there are corner cases, e.g., I'd accept *der Gipfel von [Olympus Mons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympus_Mons)*, even though that is obviously a mountain.  Or, with Band names, there seem to be some exceptions (*der Bassist der Toten Hosen* is much preferred to *der Bassist von "Tote Hosen"*, but: *von "Fünf Achterl in Ehren"* seems better than *der Fünf Achterl in Ehren*).

Comment: 'von "Tote Hosen"' would be wrong, since the name of the Band includes the article. The Band is called "Die Toten Hosen".

Comment: It would be "Der Bassist der Toten Hosen", if I am not mistaken

Comment: I do agree to both of you, but @Maeher, the difficulty I wanted to highlight is that if an article is possible at all, it can get "absorbed" into surrounding grammar: we can say both _im "Zauberberg" von Mann_ and _in "Der Zauberberg" von Mann_ -- the latter being just a bit less idiomatic, I'd say. Which variant is preferred depends on the semantics and usage of the expression in question.

Comment: 'Der Bassist der Toten Hosen', 'Der Bassist von "Die Toten Hosen"', or "Der Bassist von den Toten Hosen" would all be acceptable. *Dropping* the article is not.

Comment: @Maeher right. Whereas curiously enough, dropping ‘Toten’ _could_ be acceptable in this case: ‘Der Bassist der Hosen’ would be how fans of the band would say it.

Comment: _von den_ Um, no.

Comment: What are the three asterisks (`*`) for? Footnotes? Italics formatting? Something else?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Neither. It's a standard way in linguistics to denote an [ungrammatical example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk#Ungrammaticality).

Comment: @TaW Um, yes. At least that's completely acceptable in spoken language in Austria, and very close to standard (just like _Frau X vom ORF_).

Comment: _spoken language in Austria_ Um, yes. Two quite important restrictions..

Comment: Practically standard in another country than Germany. Still, practically standard -- and _Frau X vom ORF/den Grünen/den Würzigen Melonen_ is something you'd even read in a newspaper. And I assume also acceptable in parts of Germany.

Comment: Sure as it is here in Franconia  but the whole question was not about spoken language.

Comment: But I do admit there's a pragmatic difference of acceptability between partitive and possesive usage.

Comment: We are discussing about something different than asked in the question, anyway. But let's not worry and just stop here :D

Answer (score 1):

If you read something in the newspaper "Die Zeit" you say:

Ich habe es in "die Zeit" gelesen

or:

Ich habe es in der "Zeit" gelesen.

Both are correct, but the latter is perhaps more idiomatic.