# Eigennamen mit inkludiertem Titel richtig kennzeichnen

Tags: article

Wie gehe ich mit Eigennamen um, bei denen ein Artikel beinhaltet ist (z.B. "Der Standard" - eine Zeitung in Österreich, "Die Bild")? Wenn ich in einer wissenschaftlichen Arbeit nun die Eigennamen von bspw. Zeitungen in Hochkomma setze ("taz", "Die Welt", ...), setze ich den Artikel, wenn dieser zum Eigennamen gehört, auch unter Hochkomma? Was mache ich, wenn vor dem Eigenname eine Kontraktion ist bzw. sich der Fall des Artikels ändert (im "Standard" steht, dass ...)?

Comment: [related (english)](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/65576/36196)

Comment: Bei der Bild-Zeitung gehört der Artikel nicht zum Namen, sie heißt einfach "Bild".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalerweise ist es Teil des Namens, als Der Standard, oder "Der Standard". Man könnte nun auch *In Der Standard stand neulich ein interessanter Text* schreiben, und es wäre nicht mal falsch. Es klingt aber so hässlich, dass wir in diesem Fall *im Standard stand ...* schreiben.

Analog wäre zwar richtig zu sagen

*Ich habe mir den Der Standard abonniert*

aber auch hier wird man das "den Der" vermeiden und

*Ich habe mir den Standard abonniert*.

Schau mal dieses Besipiel:

> In Österreich gibt es eine Zeitung, die "Der Standard" heißt. Neben dem "Kurier" ist der "Standard" eine wichtige Tageszeitung.

Hier habe ich bei der ersten Nennung den Namen komplett mit Artikel geschrieben; es ist klar, dass der Artikel Teil des Namens ist. Danach ist das bekannt und ich sehe keinen Grund, den Leser immer wieder mit dieser Information zu nerven. Daher zeichne ich bei der wiederholten Nennung den Artikel nicht mehr getrennt als Namensteil aus.

Answer (score 2):

Wenn der Artikel zum Namen gehört und der Name in Anführungszeichen gesetzt wird, steht der Artikel selbstverständlich auch innerhalb der Anführungszeichen.

Ansonsten gilt auch für Eigennamen (Andührungszeichen oder nicht) normale Deklination.

Kontraktionen lassen sich vermeiden.

> Namen von Unternehmen/Firmen werden ganz normal dekliniert (gebeugt): *Der Artikel in der Frankfurter Allgemeinen Zeitung und der Artikel in der Süddeutschen Zeitung kommen zu unterschiedlichen Ergebnissen.*
> Dies ändert sich auch nicht, wenn der Firmenname in Anführungszeichen gesetzt wird: *die Strafzahlungen der „Deutschen Bank“ an den amerikanischen Fiskus.*

> Möchte man, dass der Firmenname in der Grundform erhalten bleibt (damit er etwa von Suchmaschinen leichter identifiziert werden kann), kann man einen geeigneten Gattungsbegriff voranstellen, der dann anstelle des eigentlichen Namens die entsprechenden Deklinationsmerkmale aufweist: der Artikel in der Tageszeitung Süddeutsche Zeitung / „Süddeutsche Zeitung“, die Zahlungen des Geldinstituts Deutsche Bank / „Deutsche Bank“.

Quelle: [Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Die-Deklination-von-Firmennamen)